# Running a python script asynchronously from WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to run a python script asynchronously from my WPF App because the task is time-consuming and running in synchronously causes the UI of the App to become unresponsive. Asynchronously code from the web page is not working, however. I'm working with the code form the link below. Any help is much appreciated.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C

I'm calling the method from the web page with this code snippet:

```
Click2Input3 = path + @"tensorflow\classifiers\" + name2 + @"\retrained_labels.txt";
Click2Input4 = path + @"tensorflow\classifiers\" + name2 + @"\retrained_graph.pb";
toEx2 = Click2Input + " " + Click2Input2 + " " + input2 + " " + Click2Input3 + " " + Click2Input4 + " " + inputDestination;
textOut.Text = toEx2;
ExecuteCommandSync(toEx2);
textOut.Text = result;
```

Which in essence just does this:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:\Users\Desktop\test\examples\image_retraining\retrain.py --bottleneck_dir=C:\Users\Desktop\test\dif_images\bottlenecks --how_many_training_steps=500 --model_dir=C:\Users\Desktop\test\images\inception --output_graph=C:\Users\Desktop\test\dif_images\retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=C:\Users\Desktop\test\dif_images\retrained_labels.txt --image_dir=C:\Users\Desktop\test\dif_images\star_wars
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(toEx2);
```

Are you trying to get the results of the python execution back into WPF?

Comment: Thanks but your suggestion causes my program to hang then break. My code made the program unresponsive for a couple of seconds, but overall still worked. And yes, i am trying to get the results of the python execution back to wpf.